# Reload Bluetooth Signal strength

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

So, I'm scanning for bluetooth peripherals and logging the strength of their signals.

```cs
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"Peripheral Discovered");
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)RSSI.integerValue);
}
```

At the method **centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:** I have access to the RSSI number (signal strength).

What is the best way to get a closest to realtime update of this value?!

Should I set a timer and call **scanForPeripheralsWithServices** every *X* seconds? Should I implement some sort of recursive callback?

Is there any better way to get the peripheral signal strength?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can periodically call the [`readRSSI`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/translated_content/CBPeripheral.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/readRSSI) method on the CBPeripheral object.

> **Discussion**
>
> When you call this method to retrieve the RSSI of the peripheral while
>   it is currently connected to the central manager, the peripheral calls
>   the peripheralDidUpdateRSSI:error: method of its delegate object. If
>   the RSSI value of the peripheral is successfully retrieved, you can
>   access it through the peripheral’s RSSI property.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I could call **scanForPeripheralsWithServices** periodically until I have a connected device an then periodically update the RSSI using **readRSSI**?

Comment: Once you have called scanForPeripheralsWithServices your delegate method will be called when a peripheral is detected. You don't need to call that method repeatedly

Comment: The answer to your second question is yes - you can use an NsTimer to schedule a periodic call to a method that invokes readRSSI